# EventEmitter in Angular doesn't send events to parent

Tags: angular

I have a parent component `RecipeContainerComponent` and a child component `RecipeListComponent`. I am trying to send an event from the child to the parent on a click event. Below is the code -

**RecipeListComponent**

```
@Component(...)
export class RecipeListComponent implement OnInit {

    @Output() selectedRecipe: EventEmitter<Recipe> = new EventEmitter<Recipe>();
    recipe1: Recipe = <code-to-make-object>;
    recipe2: Recipe = <code-to-make-object>;

    ngOnInit() {}
    constructor() {}

    recipeClicked(recipe: Recipe): void {
        alert('clicked'); // this is getting executed
        this.selectedRecipe.emit(recipe);
    }
}
```

**RecipeList HTML**

```
<div>
   <rb-recipe [recipe]="recipe1" (click)="recipeClicked(recipe1)"></rb-recipe>
   <rb-recipe [recipe]="recipe2" (click)="recipeClicked(recipe2)"></rb-recipe>
</div>
```

**RecipeContainerComponent**

```
@Component(...)
export class RecipesContainerComponent implements OnInit {

    selectedRecipe: Recipe;
    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}
    constructor() {}

    recipeSelectedEventHandler(recipe: Recipe) {
        alert('catching'); // this does NOT execute
    }

}
```

**RecipeContainerComponent HTML**

```
<div>
   <rb-recipe-list (selectedRecipe)="recipeSelectedEventHandler($event)"></rb-recipe-list>
</div>
```

Any idea what I might be missing? Thanks.

Comment: Where do you call `recipeClicked`? And can you remove `selectedRecipe: Recipe;` in your parent component and try again?

Comment: @echonax Added HTML code that shows from where the click event is fired. `<rb-recipe>` is just another component that handles displaying of a particular recipe. I tried removing `selectedRecipe: Recipe` from the parent, but that doesn't help (Don't think it's required to remove. I will use that local variable to save the event recipe emitted by the child).

Comment: Show `RecipeContainerComponent` html, where you are presumably saying `(selectedRecipe)="handleSelection()"` or something equivalent on the `<recipe-list>` component, right?

Comment: @torazaburo The `RecipeContainerComponent` HTML is already in the question (at the end of the code). Did you mean something else?

Comment: Its may not be answer, but: Why you use two times constructor() method in RecipesContainerComponent ?

Comment: All working as expected https://plnkr.co/edit/cazJ30ike0ZJIcNAnbFJ?p=preview

Comment: Not sure, but there could be a conflict between the property named `selectedRecipe` and the event of the same name on the child.

Comment: Shouldn't: `@Output() selectedRecipe: EventEmitter<Recipe> = new EventEmitter<Recipe>();` use an @Input()-decorator, and the `selectedRecipe: Recipe;` should have an @Output()-decorator?

Comment: @yurzui Have you changed something to make it work? My code on my system doesn't work, though I couldn't find anything that you changed.

Comment: No, i haven't. I've just copied your code

Comment: That's weird. I just tried to write a new parent and child and essentially do the same thing, and it worked. No idea why this piece of code doesn't work for me though!